# How to add UML/layer diagram in VS 2015 community

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to add UML/layer diagram to an existing solution in VS 2015 community? There is no architecture menu there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - [UML requires Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh871439.aspx#VersionSupport), as do the other architecture and modeling tools.

[image]